# Python3. Расчет при нажатии на кнопки

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Я совсем затупил и не могу понять, как при нажатии на кнопки осуществлять расчет?

У меня есть метка, две кнопки и выпадающим списком.

Из `DataFrame` я принимаю определенные значения для каждой кнопки, для выпадающего списка - это список.
У меня так же есть `QLabel` где отображается то, что пользователь получил при нажатии на кнопочки.

В класс есть два метода. 
В одном методе (`Values`) я получаю значения из *Excel*, 
в другом методе (`CalcValue`) я произвожу расчеты и отправляю в `QLabel` результат.

Как правильно принимать в (`CalcValue`) локальные переменные? Как мне произвести расчет?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'q111.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 230)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 40, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(48, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 75, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class MenuWindow(QWidget, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.CalcValue)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.CalcValue)
 #       self.comboBox.clicked.connect(self.CalcValue)

    def Values(self):
        # значения поступают из excel. Условно примим, что они постоянные
        a = 10 #Переменная для кнопки pushButton
        b = 20 #Переменная для кнопки pushButton_2
        c = [1,2,3,4,5] #Список для кнопки comboBox

    def CalcValue(self): #(self, a, b, c):
        # d = 0
        # if pushButton pressed:
        #     d -= a
        # if pushButton_2 pressed:
        #     d += b
        # # с выпадающим списком я справлюсь, когда пойму, как это работает с кнпокой
        # if comboBox pressed:
        #     d *= c[0]
        # self.label.setText(d)
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = MenuWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: и почему, когда я пишу я каждый раз здороваюсь (пишу "Добрый день!") Эта фраза исчезает из сообщения?

Comment: потому что фраза  "Добрый день!" не несет никакой полезной информации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 230)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 40, 47, 13))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 170, 127);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(48, 80, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 75, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Label"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет 1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Расчет 2"))


class MenuWindow(QWidget, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.calcValue)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.calcValue)
 #       self.comboBox.clicked.connect(self.CalcValue)
 
        self.a, self.b = None, None
        self.c = []
        self.values()

    def values(self):
        # значения поступают из excel. Условно примим, что они постоянные
        self.a = 10                         # Переменная для кнопки pushButton
        self.b = 20                         # Переменная для кнопки pushButton_2
        self.c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]            # Список для кнопки comboBox

    def calcValue(self):  #(self, a, b, c):
        sender = self.sender()
        d = 0
        if sender.text() == "Расчет 1":     # pushButton pressed:
             d -= self.a
        elif sender.text() == "Расчет 2":   # pushButton_2 pressed:
             d += self.b
             
        # # с выпадающим списком я справлюсь, когда пойму, как это работает с кнпокой
        # if comboBox pressed:
        #     d *= c[0]
        
        # self.label.setText(d)
        self.label.setNum(d)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = MenuWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё так. Спасибо, Ник! Я не хотел добавлять переменные в __init__ но сделаю именно так, как вы показали